# Google spreadsheet get complements

Tags: google-sheets, complement

[Link here to spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UrAZ8XtJkg1Pn45W4U1uZgMx0OzIeRLkPKR-MnkpdqI/edit#gid=0)

As the title says, how can I end up with cells that don't match in value, the difference/complement (set theory)?

I would prefer it with only FUNCTIONS and no script.

```
{1,2,3,4}\{1,3} = {2, 4}
```

or with letters

```
{a,b,c,d}\{a,c} = {b, d}
```

or with with space.

```
{xyz zyx, abc cba, qwe ewq}\{xyz zyx, qwe ewq} = {abc cba}
```

Comment: You need to chance the permissions on your sheet to allow anyone to view it

Comment: sorry, it is changed now. But what I have in the sheet is basically the same examples as I havecome with in here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having two arrays:

```
Array1  Array2
  1       1
  2       b
  b 
  4 
  c
```

you can get resulting array:

```
Result
  2
  4
  c
```

Try this formula:

```
=FILTER(A2:A6,ROUND(MMULT(ArrayFormula(--(A2:A6<>TRANSPOSE(B2:B4))),TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(1/ROWS(B2:B4)&"/",Rows(B2:B4)),"/"))),5)=1)
```

May be too complex for this task, could somebody edit it? Please, look at [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JZiUxvS9w7DQdjchtpRtyXcI-16Apo7oMVj0JieH94U/edit?usp=sharing)

---

**Edit**

I've found more simple way to do this, using Regular Expressions:

```
=FILTER(A2:A6,REGEXMATCH(ARRAYFORMULA("'"&A2:A6),JOIN("|",B2:B3))=false)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add one single formula at the top of your result column like this :

```
=arrayformula(if(B2:B=A2:A,,A2:A))
```

Comment: That works. If you don't want any blank spaces between the values, you can use `=filter(A2:A,A2:A<>B2:B)` instead